# Saving a string rendered by react-native-render-html

Tags: react-native, native-base, html-rendering

I'm trying to use an html string as text for mine Screen Title using native base components:

it's `this.state.title`

```html
<Header style={styles.head}>
    <Left>
        <Icon 
            name="menu" 
            onPress= {() => this.props.navigation.openDrawer()}
            />
    </Left>
    <Body>
        <Title style={styles.titcate}>{this.state.title}</Title>
    </Body>
    <Right />
</Header>
```

How can I render that before the `Title` tag?
Can I save the result of `<HTML html={this.state.title}/>` in a variable?

like:

```js
var title = <HTML html={this.state.title}/>
```

Comment: what you mean render before the Title tag?

Comment: It's a title of an article... there are some characters (like &) that i need to render like they are html code... so i'm wondering if i can render them, save the result in a variable, and after that display the variable in the < Title> var </ Title>

Answer (score 0):

There a workaround if you'd like to use a regex!

```
const htmlContent = {this.state.title};
```

```
const title= htmlContent.replace(/<[^>]+>/g, '');
```